# Buoyancy force | What is the correct way to describe and explain Buoyancy force at a macroscopic but also a microscopic perspective

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Have you ever noticed objects going down in a pool, reaching equilibrium? Often, when a submerged object (and in contact to the floor) is moved, it start going up again. Why?

This kind of scenarios motivated a discussion about buoyancy force. As I understand, when deriving an expression for Buoyancy Force, it's each section of the fluid that exerts a force on each section of an object, due to its pressure. This translates on a vertical net force that becomes 0 when it touches the floor. The other part (of the discussion) argued that it is the difference of pressures between water columns above and below the object and, that when it touched the floor, in contact with its surface, the force acting against gravity became 0.

For instance, in my mind, this is not correct because i) a cone would change its motion if I rotate it (assuming that friction is ignored), ii) an object in contact with the floor is still affected by the pressure at the sides of the body, below its center of mass, resulting in an upwards force, iii) I don't think a vacuum could form between these two surfaces usually.

**Q**: What is the correct way to describe and explain Buoyancy Force at a macroscopic but also a microscopic perspective? Which "model" is in better agreement from the presented and how do you explain the pool's submerged object example?

Comment: This question, in its current form, leaves an ambiguity concerning the word 'touching', as in 'touching the floor of a pool ot liquid'. Most likely what you have in mind is that there is still room for liquid *under* the object. This liquid underneath the object is then exerting pressure. Then 'touching' refers to the floor of the pool carrying whatever weigth is not carried by buoyancy. However, it could be, I'm not sure, that what you have in mind with 'touching' is a state of contact between floor and object so that underneath the object there is absolutely no liquid present.

Comment: It's not clear why you refer to a cone. Whether an object is buoyant is determined by one factor only: the density of the object compared to the density of the liquid that it is immersed in. If that density is less then the object has positive buoyancy, and will tend to remain at the surface of the pool. If that density is higher then the object has negative buoyancy, and once placed in the liquid it will descend. The *shape* of the object is not a factor.